# scrapy does not login to webpage using FormRequest.from_response

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I have below code to login and **scrape** given url. But login is never attempted. It moves between login and forgot password screen. I tried passing login cookie and no luck. Not sure if FormRequest.from_response ever worked for anyone. Please help..

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    handle_httpstatus_list = [401]
    start_urls = ['https://xyz/login']    
    
    def parse(self, response):
        
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'username': 'user', 'password': 'pwd='},
            callback=self.after_login
        )
       
    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            return
        
       
        for quote in response.xpath('//select'):            
            yield {
                 'url': response.url.extract(),               
                'text': quote.xpath('option::text').extract(),               
            }
                
        for next_page in response.xpath('//a/@href').extract():
            if`enter code here` next_page is not None:
                yield response.follow(next_page, self.after_login)
```

Comment: `FormRequest.from_response` wouldn't exist if it didn't work. There are multiple things that could be going wrong, but it's hard to tell what is going on without seeing actual, runnable code ([mcve]) and/or output you get.